# Alternative to static linking OpenSSL

Tags: linux, openssl, linker, static-libraries, libcrypto

I am working on a shared library loaded into application that uses libcurl and libopenssl+libcrypto. For certain reasons I have to override memory allocation functions, using `curl_global_init_mem` and `CRYPTO_set_mem_functions`. I could ensure time-separation of application and my library calling into these, but at least `CRYPTO_set_mem_functions` looks like it does not allow to cleanup & unset those functions (despite I can read the original ones). In general, I don't want to break whatever the application is doing.

Is there any alternative to statically linking all the libraries into my shared library? (Size is not *that* important but I'd miss OS security updates). As my library is loaded after the application starts, I cannot do any LD_PRELOAD tricks. Non-portable (Linux-only) solutions are acceptable.

**EDIT:** I found that while the allocations made by OpenSSL itself are configurable, in fact there are different (e.g. libc) functions called by the code that do allocate using regular malloc anyway. So in the end I have to invoke my 'plugin' code in a separate process (where I don't have to override those functions) and communicate with the main application with simple IPC (pipes in my case).